# Magento different product price starting the second product

Tags: magento

I'm working on a software online store width magento CE 1.9

the license pricing is a bit tricky:

each software product has a price for the first license, each additional license of the same product is cheaper.

for example:

```
1 license  (Product Quantity:1) 200$
2 licenses (Product Quantity:2) 200$ (main price of first license) + 20$ (price of additional license) = 220$
3 licenses (Product Quantity:3) 200$ + 2 x 20$ = 240$
4 licenses (Product Quantity:4) 200$ + 3 x 20$ = 260$
```

i already tried Tier Prices, but this would only allow reducing the price of all licenses.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any limit on the number of items you can sell? Because if you limit for example the number of licenses to be purchased to max 6, by doing some simple maths you find out that you can apply the following prices and use Tier Prices:

Price single license: 200$

```
+-----+---------+
| Qty |  Price  |
+-----+---------+
|  2  |  110$   |  = (200+20)/2   <--- The divider is #items
|  3  |   80$   |  = (200+20*2)/3
|  4  |   65$   |  = (200+20*3)/4
|  5  |   56$   |  = (200+20*4)/5
|  6  |   50$   |  = (200+20*5)/6
+-----+---------+
```

But after six numbers don't round that nicely, so this is just a partial solution. Hope it helps you anyway. :)

Comment: Unfortunately there is a limit. Thanks anyway, we will solve this using an observer.